# Project1.exe Has Stopped Working. I cant seem to find what the heel is wrong with my SDL Code

Tags: c++, sdl

All right, i apologize right away because the code is actually kind of big. The thing is, i am working with SDL, learning actually. I had managed to create animations, but i decided i wanted to go a little deeper. This is how the Code works

App - Uses: This has the main loop, the Init function, the Render Function and the whole softwares is originated from here.

Animation - Uses: This will contain and declare all of the functions in the Class Animation. It only works when a bool variable called Running is true.

Surface - Uses: This will Load files onto surfaces, Make certain color transparents and Draw images or part of images onto the MainSurface.

Events - Uses: This has all of the Virtual Functions to Events

Object - Uses: This is the big part. It was working perfectly. Before i would have a Surface Called Yoshi on the Main Class, and i would interact with the animation using that Surface. I thought that the method of having the "Character" on the main Class was a little bit confusing and it would cause me problems when having Multiple images on the screen. So therefore i decided to create a class called Object, which would have its own SDL_Surface, its own location on screen, Its own variable decided which frame it is. What i did was that i created an object to This class on the APP Class... Something like

```
Object MainCharacter;
```

So then i would be able to manipulate that Character alone, and if i ever needed to have another Object on screen i would just use

```
Object *SecondCharacter;
```

etc... So then the OBJECT Class would call the Animation. APP Class would render all of the images, by a function somewhat like this

```
MySurface::OnDraw(Surf_Display, MainCharacter.Img_Surface, MainCharacter.RetrievePosX(), MainCharacter.RetrievePosY(), MainCharacter.RetrieveFrameByID(0), MainCharacter.RetrieveFrameByID(1), 64, 64);
```

Well... But the thing is: The code stops working. This is far from a finished code, but i would like to fix this issue right away, so i can finish only after it already has a base.

Here are all of the files: Some of them dont have too many lines. I also wrote some comments to help anyone who may be able to help me.

---

### HEADERS:

Animation.h - http://pastebin.com/v4REcmBd

Object.h - http://pastebin.com/KdeamZTG

Events.h - http://pastebin.com/dpQ7zwpG

CApp.h - http://pastebin.com/5zZYwDjv

Surface.h - http://pastebin.com/S66ChQ3f

---

### SOURCES:

Surface.cpp - http://pastebin.com/KRgAkHpw

Object.cpp - http://pastebin.com/RtDRwVj4

Events.cpp - http://pastebin.com/dpXn8Rh3

OnRender.cpp - http://pastebin.com/AqgMTacb

OnLoop.cpp - http://pastebin.com/UAeAt7y6

OnInit.cpp - http://pastebin.com/1iiZVeyK

OnEvent.cpp - http://pastebin.com/AjRXnKC1

OnCleanUp.cpp - http://pastebin.com/cv0M11nV

CApp.cpp - http://pastebin.com/L0jhfWY8

Animation.cpp - http://pastebin.com/0BZhh6TG

---

All right those are it. Some of them are really short. Well, if anyone can help me finding where is my mistake i would be glad. And with that aside, i would really like to get an opinion on the structure of the software, do you think what i am doing is practical? What Design do YOU use when creating SDL Software or Games???

Comment: You will pay me, if I read all this files?

Comment: Press the debug button.

Comment: What else does your computer say, apart from "Project1.exe Has Stopped Working"? What happens when you run it in the debugger? (That will at least tell us which source file it's in - I am too busy to read all of them for you)

Comment: Oops... My Bad... All right, here... The Debugger says the problem is on Surface.cpp, line 12. There is a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Victor - you could shorten the question and include the details to avoid hemorrhaging points

Comment: Yeah... Im pretty new to this site, so i apologize... Thank you for your help though... I really appreacite it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having been told in the comments it happens on line 12 of Source.cpp which says

```
Res = SDL_DisplayFormat(Temp);
```

and googled SDL_DisplayFormat for you, I find this [manual page](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormat)

Near the bottom it says:

> **Newbie hint**
>
> You have to call SDL_Init before using the SDL_DisplayFormat function.
>   If you don't, your program will crash with an access violation.

Comment: I seem to have forgotten to Call SDL_Init... I feel like a Dumbass... I apologize and appreacite the help...

Comment: Try putting calls that must happen in constructors so you don't forget them - you have an  CApp::OnInit() function - just do that work in the constructor.